# Why does Valentine refer to her father's second wife as her "mother-in-law"?

Tags: french-language, alexandre-dumas-pere, the-count-of-monte-cristo

In the translation of *The Count of Monte Cristo* I am reading, I noticed in Chapter 51, in the exchange between Valentine and Maximillian, Valentine makes repeated reference to her father's second wife as her "mother-in-law".  Wouldn't this be her step-mother?  Your mother-in-law would be the mother of your spouse, but my understanding is Valentine is unmarried.  Also, other context clues lead me to believe this "mother-in-law" Valentine is referencing is, in fact, Madame d'Villefort.

For example, Valentine making reference to her "mother-in-law" preferring her own son, Edward, to herself.  Edward being Valentine's half-brother, the son of her father and his second wife.

Is this a mistranslation or some kind of confusion on my part?

Answer (score 23):

This is a translation error! The original French is as follows:

> — Oh! monsieur, dit-elle, pourquoi donc êtes vous venu si tard aujourd’hui? Savez-vous que l’on va dîner bientôt, et qu’il m’a fallu bien de la diplomatie et bien de la promptitude pour me débarrasser de ma **belle-mère** qui m’épie, de ma femme de chambre qui m’espionne, et de mon frère qui me tourmente, pour venir travailler ici à cette broderie, qui, j’en ai peur, ne sera pas finie de longtemps?
>
> <sub>Alexandre Dumas (1845). [*Le Comte de Monte Cristo*, volume 7, p. 283](https://archive.org/details/bnf-bpt6k5688241r/page/n291/mode/2up). Paris: Pétion.</sub>

The French “[belle-mère](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/belle-m%C3%A8re)” means both “mother-in-law” and “step-mother”, and the anonymous translator of the 1894 Crowell edition picked the wrong one:

> “And why do you come so late today? It is almost dinner-time, and I had to use no little diplomacy to get rid of my watchful **mother-in-law**, my too-devoted maid, and my troublesome brother, who is always teasing me about coming to work at my embroidery, which I am in a fair way never to get done.”
>
> <sub>Alexandre Dumas (1845). [*The Count of Monte Cristo*, volume 1, p. 516](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_Count_of_Monte_Cristo/dWlKAAAAYAAJ?gbpv=1&pg=PA516). New York: Crowell & Co (1894).</sub>

The mistake was corrected in the 1901 Crowell edition, which has “stepmother” on [page 516](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.97298/page/n547/mode/2up), but Project Gutenberg used the 1894 edition as the basis for its e-book, and the mis-translation duly appeared in chapter 51 (but no longer; see below).

[Another answer](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/19764/3003) points out that “mother-in-law” can be used with the sense “stepmother” in English too, but this doesn’t apply to *The Count of Monte Cristo*, for the following reasons:

1. The *Oxford English Dictionary* marks this sense as “now *regional*”: that is, it is not standard usage, and so is the wrong register to represent the speech of Valentine, a member of the aristocracy who has grown up in Paris.
2. The fact that Crowell issued a corrected edition shows that they considered it a mistake.
3. The translator chose “stepmother” in six other places to refer to the relationship between Valentine and Héloïse, for example, this passage:

   > Elle extra donc, et voyant près de sa **mère** l’étranger dont elle avait tant entendu parler déjà, elle salua sans aucune minauderie de jeune fille et sans baisser les yeux, avec une grâce qui redoubla l’attention du comte.
   >
   > <sub>Alexandre Dumas (1845). [*Le Comte de Monte Cristo*, volume 8, p. 7](https://archive.org/details/bnf-bpt6k5687583t/page/n17/mode/2up). Paris: Pétion.</sub>

   became, in the 1894 Crowell edition:

   > She entered the apartment, and seeing near her **stepmother** the stranger of whom she had already heard so much, saluted him without any girlish awkwardness, or even lowering her eyes, and with an elegance that redoubled the count's attention.
   >
   > <sub>Alexandre Dumas (1845). [*The Count of Monte Cristo*, volume 1, p. 526](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_Count_of_Monte_Cristo/dWlKAAAAYAAJ?gbpv=1&pg=PA526). New York: Crowell & Co (1894).</sub>

Accordingly, I submitted some [errata](https://www.gutenberg.org/help/errata.html) to Project Gutenberg, and the six occurrences of “mother-in-law” in [chapter 51](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1184/pg1184-images.html#linkC2HCH0051) are now corrected to “stepmother”, following the 1901 Crowell edition.

Comment: Is it in fact an error, or did English at the time (like French) use the term for both types of relationships?

Comment: Anothertranslation error from the same book, pointed out on this site: https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/9504/4483

Comment: @Alex Unfortunately archive.org is missing volume 2 of the 1901 Crowell edition, so I can't tell whether the "three hundred centigrammes" mistake was corrected there.

Answer (score 6):

When was this translated?

In *David Copperfield*, there are references to his "father-in-law" meaning his stepfather, so there was indeed a time when "in-law" could mean "step."

> ‘I was aware that you sustained a bereavement, sir, some time ago,’ said Mr. Chillip. ‘I heard it from your father-in-law’s sister. Very decided character there, sir?’

> ‘Why, yes,’ said I, ‘decided enough. Where did you see her, Mr. Chillip?’

> ‘Are you not aware, sir,’ returned Mr. Chillip, with his placidest smile, ‘that your father-in-law is again a neighbour of mine?’

Comment: This is the correct answer. In nineteenth-century English, *mother-in-law* could very well be used to refer to one's spouse's mother, not just to one's stepmother. It meant simply someone who was a mother by marriage, irrespective of whether the marriage was one's own or one's father's. It had the same ambiguity as *belle-mère*, and so was a perfectly legitimate translation, not a mistranslation as the accepted answer has it.

Answer (score 5):

A bit of digging has revealed the (probable) answer.

In French, both "mother-in-law" and "step-mother" are "belle-mère".  The reader/listener must use context clues to understand the difference.

The original French must have been "belle-mère" and whoever did the English translation must have, either through carelessness or confusion, went with "mother-in-law" even though "step-mother" was the real intended meaning.